# Umbraco : Automatically pick media files based on country

Tags: xpath, umbraco

I am maintaining umbraco site with the following structure:

```
Home
    UK
       Audio
         Audio1.html
         Audio2.html
       Video
         Video1.html
         Video2.html
    AU
       Audio
         Audio1.html
         Audio2.html
       Video
         Video1.html
         Video2.html
```

As of now, the html pages from two countries sharing same audio and video files. These are picked using XPath( /root/Home/Site ).

Now, I want to launch audio and video files specific to the country. I am just wondering how the XPath should be now??

For example:

If the user is accessing UK Audio1.html, then it has pick from 
`/root/Home/Site[@nodename="UK"]` .

If the user is accessing AU Audio1.html, then it has pick from 
`/root/Home/Site[@nodename="AU"]` .

How to write XPATH generically to pick from these media files automatically??

Answer (score 1):

will

```
/root/Home/Site[.="UK"]
```

and

```
/root/Home/Site[.="AU"]
```

work?

Comment: Yes. they are working. But the problem is, I want UK and AU to be populated automatically in the XPATH. Someway to fetch the node name of level 2.

Comment: @Mahesh, are use using XSLT?  Where are you using the Xpaths?